# How to pass hidden values using AJAX to another PHP file using GET method?

Tags: ajax

I’m trying to pass a hidden value that is from database to another PHP file using AJAX with GET method. But it keeps saying undefined variable. I couldn’t use a normal POST method as requirements do not want a button but a normal url link.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#edit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"editItem.php",
                data:"itemid=" + $(this.find(":selected").val()),
                cache: false,
                success: function(msg){

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="hidden" name="itemid" id="edit"/>
<a href="editItem.php">Edit</a>
```

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="itemid" value="<?php echo $theid; ?>" id="edit" />
<a href="editItem.php">Edit</a>

Comment: above is the input type